# How to disable sorting on table initialization

Tags: jquery, django, sorting, datatables

I am using jquery datatables plugin with server side processing in my django project.

I want to show the latest inserted record from mysql database to jquery datatable. Currently when I reload the page, table data is getting sorted in ascending order of first column by default. I do not want this. Is there a way to show the data as it is sent from the server on page load?. And later on clicking a column sorting should be done for the respective colummn. How can I do this? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use this and try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable({
    "order": []
});
```

});

Have a look at this https://datatables.net/reference/option/order

Comment: Still it is sorting the first column in asc order by default

Answer (score 0):

```
    here is sample code to initialize data table plugin 

    var oTable = $('.datatable').dataTable({
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "bJQueryUI": false,
                        "sDom": '<"H">t<"F"ip>',
                        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
                        "iDisplayLength": 10,
                        "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
                        "oLanguage": { "oPaginate": { "sNext": '>', "sLast": '>>', "sFirst": '<<', "sPrevious": '<'} }                    
                    });


in above initialization we have to remove "aaSorting" paramater. 


    var oTable = $('.datatable').dataTable({
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "bJQueryUI": false,
                        "sDom": '<"H">t<"F"ip>',
                        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
                        "iDisplayLength": 10,
                        "oLanguage": { "oPaginate": { "sNext": '>', "sLast": '>>', "sFirst": '<<', "sPrevious": '<'} }                    
                    });
```